# How to turn-off the output's generator Agilent using Labview

Tags: generator, labview

I have a VI that controls the voltage and frequency of the output's generator Agilent,  and I would like to know how to activate / deactivate the output, since I don't want to have to do this manually. I want to do this so that when the VI finishes running, the generator is turned off or at least the output is disabled.

Any help or suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I solve my problem with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808163/how-to-turn-off-the-outputs-generator-agilent-using-labview/7823951#7823951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve my problem with VI's Labview called (view help's Labview)

> OutputEnable

and I put my program that when finnish execute that VI.

With this, the generator continues on, only the output is disabled.

That's is all that I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Most Agilent equipment implements the [SCPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments) command set ([Agilent's SCPI learning page](http://www.home.agilent.com/agilent/editorial.jspx?cc=US&lc=eng&ckey=1688330&id=1688330)).  The specific commands you need depend on your instrument.

Without knowing the instrument, it's a little harder to say exactly what you would do, but in general, you would:

1. Physically connect to the instrument using GPIB, USB, RS232, or Ethernet.
2. Communicate to the instrument using the [VISA primitives](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361E-01/TOC107.htm).
3. Send the OUTP ON or OUTP OFF command.
4. (You can actually use commands like VOLT or FREQ to control voltage and frequency, as well.)

Look up the documentation for your instrument to know the specific commands.  The correct document will typically have something like "Programmer's Manual" or "User's Manual" in the title.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to include a model number, I can be specific. Generally speaking though once you have the unit in a remote state you send it a output on or output off command. How you do so is dependent on interface (GPID, RS232, LXI, etc) and whether you use standard commands or possibly even download a ready made VI. (Agilent provides a lot of VI sets for their instruments).

If you haven't gotten it resolve already, please comment with your Model number and the type of interface you are using and I'll be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to know what commands are required to turn the generator off or disable the output (you mean make it 0V?). If you know that, then just place the code in your shutdown state or however you exit out of your application.

Comment: But I don't know which are those commands (shutdown or exit out), where can I find it this info?